# Unable to uninstall Magento 2 Luma Theme - "frontend/Magento/luma is not an installed Composer package"

Tags: magento2, composer, luma-theme

I am running a Magento 2.3.6 system and I built my own theme which inherits from Magento/blank. Since I don't need the Luma theme, I want to properly get rid of it.
I followed the [instructions from magento dev](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-theme-uninstall.html) and tried to remove the theme via ssh console:

```
php bin/magento theme:uninstall --backup-code frontend/Magento/luma
```

However, I can't because of this error:

```
frontend/Magento/luma is not an installed Composer package
```

This is very confusing because on my cloned stage server it worked smoothly and I did not change any composer packages or manually edits.

So I checked all my files and tried to verify the frontend/Magento/luma location. I can see from multiple commands, that frontend/Magento/luma is definitely available and shown.

I also checked the folder at

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma
```

and all the necessary files like
`composer.json` `registration.php` `theme.xml` are there.

What am I missing? The theme is obviously installed and all the files are there. I was expecting some dependency issues but not this.

Comment: this error happens when entry for luma theme is missing from `theme` table in the database. Did you check if it still exists there ?

Comment: Yes, it exists: theme_path: Magento/luma - theme_title: Magento Luma

Comment: Have found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with my SSH environment. Apparently, a new `composer.json` was created in the root folder of my server. Somehow the references were messed up even though other folders (with stages) were not affected. After removing the file, it worked.